# Unable to receive UDP Packet in WPF Application

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I need a simple connectionless ClientServer application to exchange a bunch of information with a wireless device.

Before to talk about problems I'll show what I've till now:

Environment: C#, WPF, .NetFramework 4.7.1, Visual Studio 2017

Logical Organization: UDP -> UDPServer -> UDPSpecServer; UDP -> UDPClient

Code:

```
// Server App ctor
endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, connPort));
```

which should basically means that I accepts packets from everyone at specified ip (localhost) / port (1984). At some point in the code I have:

```
public void StartReceivingConnectionless()
{
    IAsyncResult result;
    try
    {
        result = socket.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, MAX_UDP_PACKET_DIMENSION, SocketFlags.None, ref endPoint, new AsyncCallback(MessageReceived), buffer);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

which should basically means that my server object starts to wait for incoming data, while the MessageReceived method:

```
public virtual void MessageReceived(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    int bytes = socket.EndReceiveFrom(asynchronousResult, ref endPoint);
    StartReceivingConnectionless();
}
```

And finally, for Serverside:

```
public void StopReceivingConnectionless()
{
    socket.Close();
}
```

While on client:

```
// Clientapp ctor
client = new FST.Lib.NetworkCommunication.UDPClient("localhost", "0");

// On-click somewhere
client.SendConnectionless(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world"), new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1984));
```

1) I still have to undesterstand why/how, but sometimes the app works, sometimes no: why?

2) The stopreceveing method is placed in the "Window_closing" event of main window, no matter what, it generates a disposed object exception because it generate a message which is recevied. Where should I put it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part 1) - it seems that my Virtual Machines was the problem. I replicated the same library at home and everything went fine. In this case, I solved using UdpClient with less or more the same architecture.

Part 2) is still a partial puzzle: I was missing the call to socket.Shutdown(); and then socket.Close(); as pointed out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.close?view=netframework-4.8) but this call generates a message received from the same socket causing the crash.

I'm accepting this answer, but more detailed ones are still welcome.